# Convertir "if (isset())" al condicional "? :" (operador ternario)

Tags: php

Tengo este código:

```
if (isset($array[$a]['estado']))
{
    echo "True";
}
else
{ 
    echo "False";
}
```

Quiero saber si lo puedo pasar al formato condicional `? :`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para darte un poco más de información, lo que buscas se denominan [operadores ternarios](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) y sí, se pueden realizar en PHP.

Estos operadores ternarios funcionan de la siguiente manera:

```
condicion ? resultadoTrue : resultadoFalse
```

Por lo tanto, traduciendo tu `if`, tal y como ha comentado `@Muriano`, sería:

```
echo isset($array[$a]['estado']) ? "True" : "False"
```

En caso de que tengas una versión de PHP 5.3 o superior podrías suprimir la parte intermedia del operador ternario quedando:

```
condicion ?: resultadoFalse
```

Y te devolvería el valor de `condicion` en caso de ser verdadero o `resultadoFalse` en caso de que la condición fuera falsa.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo isset($array[$a]['estado']) ? "True" : "False";
```